# IAM policy on S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-transcribe

I always get confused in two but I wanted to add a IAM policy on S3 bucket.
Basically I have created an output bucket for Amazon transcriptions but it seems I need to add IAM role to allow Transcription job to write to the bucket. I think if I can attach AmazonTranscribeFullAccess to S3 bucket, it will work but I am unable to attach this policy. Could you please advise how can I add this policy on the new bucket?

Comment: Do you own the bucket that Transcribe is saving to? That is, does your IAM User have permission to write to the bucket? If you run a transcription job, what error message do your receive?

Comment: Yes I own the bucket where transcribe job is saving. So basically I have access to bucket. I see you mean to say, since my IAM user created the Job and bucket both so job should have access to write to the bucket? I have not been able to run the job since the output bucket needs bucket name in some format which I am unable to get. I tried bucket url and ARN but it does not work. Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few concepts you will want to dig deeper into to understand the difference between IAM policies and S3 bucket policies. A detailed guide is: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-s3-evaluates-access-control.html

You can attach IAM policies to Users, Groups and Roles, and you can attach bucket policies to S3 buckets.

Try adding S3 access to the user/role that you are using to run the transcribe job.